# Mac Pro Stuck at login window - Updated Big Sur

Tags: big-sur, performance, login-screen

I have Mac Pro 2019 Model.
Updated from Catalina to Big Sur 11.5

Stuck at after entering password. Password accepted and Mac froze.

Froze with all accounts including 2 admin and 1 local user (Tried with wrong password to get rejection - Rejected)

Solutions tried

1. PRAM & SMC reset - Failed
2. Safe mode - Failed
3. Reinstall operating system from recovery mode - Failed
4. Disk repair from Disk utility at Recovery mode - Failed
5. Changing password using terminal from Recovery mode - Failed
6. 4. times called apple support - Failed
7. Tried to create new admin user by removing .AppleSetupDone - This stuck at language choose -Failed
8. Failed to create a new operating system with external hard disk (External Drive boot is enabled from recovery mode) - Failed
9. Created partition on same SSD and installed new operating system in new partition - Successfully copied the files. But can't access the application folder to copy some application, which are contains the preferences inside to them itself. Fortunately I could copy most my files except the applications

Before formatting entire drive I like to try any solutions possible to recover previous files, settings especially applications and its preferences

**Qusestion1** . Do any one know other solutions like delete or edit any files or folders which stopping the login?

**Question2**. Any solution other than format and install a fresh operating system

Comment: Many of these could do with an addendum… "Failed: result was  xyz error etc. Just 'failed' doesn't really help diagnosis.

Comment: 1. Are you able to get into single-user mode (CMD+S during boot)? 2. (Optional for now) Can you boot using verbose mode (CMD+V during boot) and get a slow-mo video capture of the process and share framegrabs? 3. How long did you wait before rebooting? I'm suspecting that something is holding up account upgrade so we may need to get creative to get a stackshot. If you don't want to root-cause, one possible workaround is to use Migration Assistant to fully move over to your new partition.

Comment: @Tetsujin Failed means , I couldn't login to my account after executing all these Solutions. PRAM reset end up with black screen, and restart send back to the login window and froze after. Safe mode also froze after login

Comment: @pion Tried both  single user and Verbose both end with black screen.
I wait around a hour several times after login.
I tried migration assistant but it needs to start the assistant at both drive, unfortunately I can't login to the previous drive

Comment: @MuhammedNoufal Did you see any console text output during verbose boot? If so, can you capture slo-mo frames as I mentioned above?